# If interfaces are only allowed to be public, how does this work

Tags: java, interface

This is the below code which compiles successfully

```
 import java.util.*;
    class Test
    {
        protected interface Yes
        {
            void show();
        }
    }
    
    class Testing extends Test implements Test.Yes
    {
        public void show()
        {
            System.out.println("show method of interface");
        }
    }
    
    class A
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Test.Yes obj;
            Testing t = new Testing();
            obj=t;
            obj.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: **nested** classes/interfaces can have any visibility

Comment: "If interfaces are only allowed to be public" what makes you think so?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is incorrect - see the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1), section 9.1.1.

> The access modifiers protected and private pertain only to member
> interfaces whose declarations are directly enclosed by a class
> declaration (§8.5.1).

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces itself can have any visibility that classes can have. For top-level interfaces that's limited to public and package-private, for nested interfaces it can be anything.

Until Java 9, everything *inside* interfaces had to be public, and everything without an explicit visibility modifier automatically was. Java 9 made it possible to add private methods to interfaces, which can be called by default method implementations.

Note that protected inside interfaces is still not allowed, and package-private cannot be used because members without an explicit public or private modifier are automatically public.

Comment: @passer-by yes of course, thanks. I've fixed it.